# Does #region code harm my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using #region to collapse some big code. Does it harm my code? And i'm not using any third party tools like Resharper with visual studio.

Comment: What do you mean by **harm**?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell  and  http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/   Just say no to #region (imho)... If you have "big code" fix it by refactoring, not by attempting to hide it.

Comment: Please read this link, I think you will get correct answer
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118818/why-are-people-so-strongly-opposed-to-region-tags-in-methods

Comment: This reminds me about one bug that was in Visual Studio 2002 :) When you copied code that has #region element inside, the code inside #region element was not copied. It caused a lot of confusion before we finally figured out what's the source of that strange behavior.

Comment: harm means bad effect on code execution...

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't impact the output in any way. It is probably a sign that your class has grown too big and coupled (doing things that could be delegated/abstracted somewhere else), so it would need a bit of refactoring.

But once it is compiled, it will be the same with `#region` or without it